# how to make hashable datatype to use with jit?

Tags: jax

What would be a workaround of this code in jitted function?

`j = indices.index(list(neighbor))`
where `neighbor` is, for example, `(2,3)`, `indices = [[1,2], [4,5], ...]`

I've tried several other alternatives like partial but didn't work. One issue when using `partial` is that indices is not hashable so can't use partial function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.index` is a Python function that will not work within JIT if the contents of the list are traced values. I would recommend converting your lists to arrays, and do something like this:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

indices = jnp.array([[1, 2], [4, 5], [3, 6], [2, 3], [5, 7]])
neighbor = jnp.array([2, 3])

@jax.jit
def get_index(indices, neighbor):
  return jnp.where((indices == neighbor).all(-1), size=1)[0]

idx = get_index(indices, neighbor)
print(idx)
# [3]
```

Comment: I was wondering why your solution works because, to my understanding, in jitted function the methods that require concrete values (`indices == neighbor` in this case I think) are not compatible with `jit`. The `jnp.where` document says: "Alternatively, you can use the optional size keyword to statically specify the expected size of the output." 
Does that mean when `size` parameter is given, it behaves like the `static_argnums` parameter of `partial` function? I just confirmed your solution doesn't work without `size` parameter but does work with it.

Comment: `indices == neighbor` itself does not require concrete values – it returns a traced boolean array. Regarding `jnp.where`: the semantics of `np.where` are to return a dynamically-shaped array, which is not compatible with JIT and other transformations. Specifying `size` statically makes the output size static.